# JavaScript canvas pie chart warping issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pie-chart

I am trying to create a custom HTML element that allows me to create pie charts easily.
I have been very successful so far except for the fact that I cant seem to get the actual canvas drawing to be proportioned correctly.

```js
class PieChart extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.classList.add('pie-chart')
        this.innerHTML = `<canvas style="width:100%; height:100%;"></canvas>`
        this.style.display = 'block'
        this.ctx = this.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d')

        const results = [
            {mood: "Angry", total: 1599, shade: "#0a9627"},
            {mood: "Happy", total: 478, shade: "#960A2C"},
            {mood: "Melancholic", total:332, shade: "#332E2E"},
            {mood: "Gloomy", total: 195, shade: "#F73809"},
            {mood: "Eh", total: 195, shade: "#000000"}
        ];

            this.chartify(results);
        

    }

    chartify(results){
        var el_width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        var half = (el_width / 2);
        let sum = 0;
        let portion = results.reduce((sum, {total}) => sum + total, 0);
        let currentAngle = 0;
    
        for (let moodValue of results) {
            //calculating the angle the slice (portion) will take in the chart
            let portionAngle = (moodValue.total / portion) * 2 * Math.PI;
            //drawing an arc and a line to the center to differentiate the slice from the rest
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.arc(half, half, half, currentAngle, currentAngle + portionAngle);
            currentAngle += portionAngle;
            this.ctx.lineTo(half, half);
            //filling the slices with the corresponding mood's color
            this.ctx.fillStyle = moodValue.shade;
            this.ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}

window.customElements.define('pie-chart', PieChart);
export{PieChart};
```

this is the returned result

[image]

The custom element is designed to have dynamic size. So to draw the arcs I was dividing the width by 2 in order to get the midpoint. I figured this would also be the radius. then all I need is to calculate the angle which I have no problem with. Why is it that the pie chart is oblong and not taking up the full space? What am I doing wrong in my canvas draw code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) has default values for its `height` and `width` attributes of `150` and `300`, respectively. If you need your canvas to be square, you need to specify these sizes to be the same.

This example tweaks your `el_width` variable to read the width off the canvas directly, instead of using `getBoundingClientRect`. I've also tweaked the way the `canvas` element is created so it has `width` and `height` attributes, and its 100% width and height styles are set via CSS:

```js
class PieChart extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback(){
        this.classList.add('pie-chart')
        this.innerHTML = `<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>`
        this.style.display = 'block'
        this.ctx = this.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d')

        const results = [
            {mood: "Angry", total: 1599, shade: "#0a9627"},
            {mood: "Happy", total: 478, shade: "#960A2C"},
            {mood: "Melancholic", total:332, shade: "#332E2E"},
            {mood: "Gloomy", total: 195, shade: "#F73809"},
            {mood: "Eh", total: 195, shade: "#000000"}
        ];

            this.chartify(results);
        

    }

    chartify(results){
        var el_width = this.ctx.canvas.width;
        var half = (el_width / 2);
        let sum = 0;
        let portion = results.reduce((sum, {total}) => sum + total, 0);
        let currentAngle = 0;
    
        for (let moodValue of results) {
            //calculating the angle the slice (portion) will take in the chart
            let portionAngle = (moodValue.total / portion) * 2 * Math.PI;
            //drawing an arc and a line to the center to differentiate the slice from the rest
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.arc(half, half, half, currentAngle, currentAngle + portionAngle);
            currentAngle += portionAngle;
            this.ctx.lineTo(half, half);
            //filling the slices with the corresponding mood's color
            this.ctx.fillStyle = moodValue.shade;
            this.ctx.fill();
        }
    }
}

window.customElements.define('pie-chart', PieChart);
```

```css
pie-chart {
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

pie-chart canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<pie-chart></pie-chart>
```

You'll also notice that if you use `width` and `height` values that are smaller than the actual size at which the canvas is displayed, it will be noticeably scaled up since it's producing a raster image rather than a vector one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your were right. all i needed to do was set `canvas.height` and `canvas.width` to the element with and it cleared up the issue. For some reason i though using css would do the trick too though.